# Azure Storage api doesn't work for asnyc uploads

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload so many files via Azure Blob Storage .NET api and using with the current latest version 4.0.1. In ASP.NET MVC application i use async action method to upload via await blobFile.UploadFromStreamAsync but it really doesn't work and even i don't see an exception. It silently stops in that method without success.

But if i change action method to none-async and upload via blobFile.UploadFromStream method then everything to works well. I may uploaded via async way with 1% success rate that means very very low stability.

Do you experience same thing ? Is it bug in Storage Api implementation ?

Here is short example. One is async and the other one is none async action methods. There is no any problem if i upload small files but problem appears on large downloads. In this example UploadBlobSec method upload in short time but UploadBlob takes endless time.

```
    public async Task UploadBlob()
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureStorage"].ConnectionString);
        var blobContainer = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("files");
        var blobFile = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("song.mp3");

        using (var stream = new WebClient().OpenRead("http://apolyonstorage.blob.core.windows.net/files/e8b1a1fa-8791-44dc-92ce-1a67a62f7b0f.mp3"))
        {
            await blobFile.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
        }
    }

    public void UploadBlobSec()
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureStorage"].ConnectionString);
        var blobContainer = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("files");
        var blobFile = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("song.mp3");

        using (var stream = new WebClient().OpenRead("http://apolyonstorage.blob.core.windows.net/files/e8b1a1fa-8791-44dc-92ce-1a67a62f7b0f.mp3"))
        {
            blobFile.UploadFromStream(stream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @usr You can't be sure about this. I have nothing to do with my own code. Just everything works fine if i don't prefer async upload.

Comment: Come on i am experienced developer and i wouldn't suspect that this can be a bug in the api. I don't think that uploading in async way used by thousand developers. It is much less than you thought.

Comment: I will provide simplified and tested example to here soon.

Comment: @usr Can you please test this examples if you have a time ? I am sure you will encounter same problem.

Comment: Code looks fine. Is this *all* that's going on? Maybe the caller is calling `Wait` on the task returned by `UploadBlob`. That is a common deadlock situation. Does the issue repro in a fresh, nearly empty ASP.NET MVC app with an async controller? If yes, that would indeed look like a bug. But I don't think it will because it would mean that this method is 100% unusable. That would have been found already.

Comment: @usr I tested it with the current code that upload file that is 4.3MB and download completed after huge time. But none async version was able to upload very quickly. And i was also tried to upload 10MB file and i couldn't wait to finish because it already takes huge time.

Comment: And the app is empty otherwise besides this minimal repro code? I don't have an Azure account handy to test.

Comment: I haven't tested in empty app but i am sure it is not about that. Anyway i will post it to ugly microsoft forums or may be github issues

Answer (score 1):

Code snippet looks fine - although I am not sure what the application around it is doing. Have you turned on server logs to see what is happening server side? For large files you should see the async upload translated into a couple of PutBlocks and then a PutBlockList. If you don't see the PutBlockList them maybe something strange is happening in your application.

Then assuming you do see the operations in the server logs that obviously means the operations are occurring. At that point look at the E2ELatency numbers vs ServerLatency I think you will see a large difference with E2Latency being much higher as it incorporates the time spent client side - and it would be interesting to see if your client network could be contributing to the problem. For example on my connection the e2elatency on the first PutBlock was 1346 ms vs 137 for ServerLatency.

For more information on logging take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/08/03/windows-azure-storage-logging-using-logs-to-track-storage-requests.aspx).

Jason